# python -m http.server gives "Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ..." Vs "Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ..."

Tags: python, http.server

I'm very inexpert at this but when I use on different projects:

```
python -m http.server
```

a project answers with:

```
Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...
```

the other with:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

I visit the pages on:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

it works in either cases but there is a difference?

The projects are simply sphinx documents (I use miniconda on windows, different version of python and sphinx but the configuration should be almost the same). The `sys.path` has the same shape. Sorry but I have no idea what you need to know, so ask me.

Thank you

Comment: [::] is for ipv6 and 0.0.0.0 is for ipv4. Both means bind 8000 on all interfaces.

Comment: @tbhaxor thank you, but like I said I'm ignorant on this, so what? Should I ignore the difference?

Comment: Yes, you should. Basically the http.server module prioritize ipv6 if available otherwise go for ipv4.

Comment: Are both projects run on the same computer? There probably is a difference in python versions between the two?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, they are on the same pc but they use different python (and sphinx) versions installed on different conda environments.